# WCF Data Contract / Data Class

Tags: c#, wcf

I am building a application that will expose some functionality using WCF web services.

I have a data class that is used throughout the app that I now want to use in the web services (I have simplified the below just for example).  The trouble I am having is working out how to use the data class in the web service without including it in the interface as a DataContract.  Im having a real blonde moment (no offence to blondes) and cannot figure it out.

So my solution:

[image: Solution]

My Web Service:

[image]

Web Service Interface with the Data Contract declared here all is fine:

[image]

But I want to use the ErrorRequest in DataClasses

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options: Separate DataClasses to another Class Library and reference it in both projects (Common / WebServices) or create a copy of ErrorRequest in your webservices.

I would go with first option.